# Windows Forms - Open suggestions list programatically after setting the autocomplete source

Tags: winforms, autocomplete

I'm having a textbox in my windows form for which I'm having autocomplete configured. I'm bringing the suggestions dynamically as the user types from a web serivce. This is done by a background worker.

After setting the autocomplete source how can I open the suggestions of that textbox programatically? (Something like a property we have for combobox - DroppeDown)

Answer (score 1):

Your options are:

1. use a hacky solution
2. use a pure C# autocomplete control (e.g. write your own or use someone else's)
3. switch to combobox

You can find #2 and #3 on your own.  I think #2 is the best option.  However, read on if you want to do #1:

A clean solution to what you are asking for doesn't exist.  My understanding of autocomplete is that it is a COM object, probably originally built for Internet Explorer (as the Spy++ window has "Internet Explorer" title in its hierarchy).  Anyway, the autocomplete hooks into the WndProc events from the editing control.  It populates and displays the list when it receives notifications events such as KEY_DOWN.

For example, suppose you have an autocomplete with at least one word starting with the letter 'A'.  You can force the autocomplete to appear by sending a POST message to the TextBox:

```
//host.Text = "A"; // does not work
PostMessage(textbox.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_A, 0); // works (see SendKey method below)

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);


// only works once the Handle has been assigned
public void Show() {
    ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
}

// e.g. VK_A = 0x41, VK_SPACE = 20;
public void SendKey(int VK_KEY) {
    PostMessage(Host.Handle, 0x100, VK_KEY, 0);
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run((Action) delegate {
        Thread.Sleep(10); // small delay required
        Host.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate {
            Show();
        });
    });
}
```

As far as I know, it's not possible to directly control the contents in the autocomplete.  However, in another stackoverflow thread (can't find it now), the answer was to prefix each word with a space so that they all shared a common prefix, and then trim the value afterwards.

You can also force the autocomplete to appear without typing anything, but unfortunately it will be empty.  For example:

```
const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
IntPtr p = ...; // handle to Autocomplete window
int width = 400;
int height = 200;
SetWindowPos(p, IntPtr.Zero, -5, 0, width, height, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
ShowWindow(p, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
```

You can find out how to get the handle reference here: [Combo box drop down width on suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820429/combo-box-drop-down-width-on-suggest)

Even once you have the handle, there is no direct or indirect link to its owning editing control.  In the hyperlink above, the only way to determine the editing control is to listen for the first time the autocomplete is displayed, and then check each control to see which control's on screen bounding box contains it.

Comment: Wow. Appears so hacky for such a simple use case. Will try it.

Comment: I was pretty sure `PostMessage` was working, but seems like I changed something in my code and it's not working now.  Anyway, if it's not working, you can do `control.Focus(); SendKeys.Send(" ");`

Comment: Seems like a small delay followed by a `Show()` can fix the problem.  Added the code that works for me using `PostMessage`.