# NativeWindows, ComboBox and UserControl in WinForm (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

I am truly destroyed by this principle that I will now explain. I did use the code for the answer mentioned in this article ([Combo box drop down width on suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820429/combo-box-drop-down-width-on-suggest)).
The code works fine when it comes to inheriting a ComboBox. Exactly as in the following code:

```
public class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
{
    ... //(See the code in the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820429/combo-box-drop-down-width-on-suggest)

    private class ACWindow : NativeWindow
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Well, as I said above, if I use the ComboBoxEx class in my Forms, this works fine: I can handle the size of the AutoComplete window.
But if I use the ComboBoxEx class in a UserControl and then insert UserControl into my Form, it will no longer work.
From various attempts I understand (perhaps) that the WndProc method of the ACWindow class is not executed for any reason.
Why are not Windows messages forwarded to UserControl's children controls?

In other words, the code I use is almost the following:

```
// UserCOntrol class declaration
public class MyCmbControl : UserControl
{
    ComboBoxEx ExtendedCombo = new ComboBoxEx();
    ....
}
// Form class declaration
public class MyForm : Form
{
     protected ComboBoxEx Cmb1 = new ComboBoxEx(); //-- This work fine!!
     protected MyCmbControl Cmb2 = new MyCmbControl(); //-- This will no longer work
}
```

**NOTE:**

- The UserControl control has the ComboBoxEx control as the only child
- I tried to move the ACWindows class at UserControl level
- I tried sending a 0x0047 (WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED) message to the ComboBoxEx member of MyCmbControl

All this without getting good results...
I thank you in advance for the help you will give me and I apologize for the incorrect english I'm using in this post !!!

Comment: What is the error or issue? no longer work means what?